# App crashes while clicking some tabs on tabLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-tablayout

I am working on an Android app, that would have 4 tabs with 4 fragments. I have run the app on my Android device. But the problem I am encountering is that,  when I click on the first 2 tabs, it works fine, but when I open the 3rd and 4th tab, APP CRASHES IMMEDIATELY!

Initially, I thought there was a  bug on the 3rd and 4th fragments, but I later discovered that this is not a 3rd or 4th fragment bug. I replaced the 1st and 2nd fragments with the 3rd and 4th fragment, and the 1st and 2nd fragments replaced with the 3rd and 4th fragments. And the same thing still happened!

This is my main_activity.java.

```
public class Main_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Bind(R.id.main_activity)
View mView;
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.friend_chat,
        R.drawable.call,
        R.drawable.tab_contact,
        R.drawable.profile
};
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

private NonSwipeableViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, new ConversationsFragment()).commit();


    viewPager = (NonSwipeableViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    setupTabIcons();

}

   private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);

    int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(Main_Intergister.this, R.color.holo_red_dark);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a0a3a7"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a0a3a7"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a0a3a7"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);


    ColorStateList colors;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        colors = getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.ash, getTheme());
    }
    else {
        colors = getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.ash);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        assert tab != null;
        Drawable icon = tab.getIcon();

        if (icon != null) {
            icon = DrawableCompat.wrap(icon);
            DrawableCompat.setTintList(icon, colors);
        }
    }

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);


            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    break;
                case 1:
                  viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                case 3:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a0a3a7"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {


        }
    });
}

    private void setupViewPager(NonSwipeableViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new ConversationsFragment(), "Chats");
    adapter.addFragment(new ContactsFragment(), "Calls");
    adapter.addFragment(new CallsFragment(), "Contacts");
    adapter.addFragment(new Profile_fragment(), "Profile");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

 class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
    }
     }
 }
```

This is my main_activity.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_activity"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

           <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            android:id="@+id/appbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_app_name"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <com.solid.helpers.NonSwipeableViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="8dp"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:background="@color/white"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>



   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: Could not find the error from logcat.

Answer (score 6):

Since you have 4 tabs, please try adding the following code under main_activity onCreate event and see would it solve your issue.

viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);